# Xgboost with Smote on imbalanced data

Tags: xgboost, smote

attached is the code for xgboost on ftir data with smote and smote_weights. the results based on smote is attached as image. From the confusion matrix, i understood that even after applying smote, class 0 is not being utilized in any fold.
So i try to include sample weights and end up with following error.

```
'''
with smote
'''

import time
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, classification_report, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline as ImbPipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns



def evaluate_model_performance(y_true, y_pred, model):
    """
    Evaluate and display the performance of the trained model.
    """
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
    precision = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
    recall = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
    print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}, Precision: {precision:.4f}, Recall: {recall:.4f}")
    print("\nClassification Report:\n", classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d')
    plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
    plt.ylabel('Actual label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.show()
    if hasattr(model, 'feature_importances_') and model.feature_importances_.any():
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
        xgb.plot_importance(model, max_num_features=10)
        plt.title("Feature importances")
        plt.show()

def display_class_distribution(y):
    """
    Display the distribution of classes in the label array.
    """
    unique, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
    distribution = pd.DataFrame({'Class': unique, 'Count': counts})
    print(distribution)

def create_class_distribution_df(y):
    unique, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
    distribution_df = pd.DataFrame({'Class': unique, 'Count': counts})
    distribution_df['Percentage'] = distribution_df['Count'] / distribution_df['Count'].sum() * 100
    # Filter out classes with zero counts
    distribution_df = distribution_df[distribution_df['Count'] > 0]
    return distribution_df

# Start timing
tic = time.perf_counter()

# Data Loading and Preprocessing

print("Loading data...")
Mat = sio.loadmat("/content/drive/MyDrive/Codes/Xgboost_fasa/R_FASA_Binned_spectra_all.mat")
spectraTissue = Mat['spectraTissue']
spectraTissue = savgol_filter(spectraTissue, 5, 4, 0, axis=0)
NHG = [int(x) for x in Mat['label'].T]
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(NHG)
patientNo = Mat['patientNo'].T
print("Size of spectraTissue:", spectraTissue.shape)

# Initial Class Distribution
print("Initial class distribution:")
display_class_distribution(y)

# Model Training and Evaluation

train_perf, test_perf, fold_details, f1_train_scores, f1_test_scores, hyperparameters, class_distribution = [], [], [], [], [], [], []
nsplits = 5
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=nsplits, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

print("Starting cross-validation with SMOTE...")
for fold, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(skf.split(spectraTissue, y), start=1):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = spectraTissue[train_index], spectraTissue[test_index], y[train_index], y[test_index]

    # Pipeline for GridSearchCV with SMOTE
    pipeline = ImbPipeline([
        ('smote', SMOTE(random_state=42)),
        ('classifier', xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softprob', eval_metric='mlogloss'))
    ])
    paramspace = {
        'classifier__n_estimators': [50, 100, 200],
        'classifier__max_depth': [3, 5, 7],
        'classifier__learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1, 0.2],
        'classifier__subsample': [0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
        'classifier__colsample_bytree': [0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
    }
    grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=paramspace, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42), scoring='f1_macro', verbose=2)
    mod = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Apply SMOTE to the training data
    X_resampled, y_resampled = mod.best_estimator_.named_steps['smote'].fit_resample(X_train, y_train)

    # Calculate the class distribution after SMOTE
    resampled_distribution_df = create_class_distribution_df(y_resampled)
    print(f"\nClass distribution after SMOTE in fold {fold}:")
    print(resampled_distribution_df)

    print("Unique classes after SMOTE:", np.unique(y_resampled))

    # Predict and evaluate
    preds_train = mod.predict(X_train)
    preds_test = mod.predict(X_test)
    train_f1, test_f1 = f1_score(y_train, preds_train, average='macro'), f1_score(y_test, preds_test, average='macro')
    f1_train_scores.append(train_f1)
    f1_test_scores.append(test_f1)
    train_perf.append(train_f1)
    test_perf.append(test_f1)
    hyperparameters.append(mod.best_params_)
    class_distribution.append(np.bincount(y_train))

    # Store fold details
    fold_details.append({
        'Fold': fold,
        'Train Size': len(X_train),
        'Test Size': len(X_test),
        'Best Params': mod.best_params_,
        'Train F1 Score': train_f1,
        'Test F1 Score': test_f1
    })

    # Output performance evaluation for the fold
    evaluate_model_performance(y_test, preds_test, mod.best_estimator_)

# Calculate the average class distribution after SMOTE
print("\nAverage class distribution after SMOTE across folds:")
avg_class_distribution = np.mean(class_distribution, axis=0)
distribution_df = create_class_distribution_df(avg_class_distribution.astype(int))

# Display the class distribution
print(distribution_df)

# Save the class distribution to a CSV file
distribution_csv_path = "average_class_distribution_after_smote.csv"
distribution_df.to_csv(distribution_csv_path, index=False)
print(f"Class distribution after SMOTE saved to {distribution_csv_path}")

# Results Visualization

# F1 Score Across Folds Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
folds = list(range(1, nsplits + 1))
plt.plot(folds, f1_train_scores, label='Train F1 Score', marker='o')
plt.plot(folds, f1_test_scores, label='Test F1 Score', marker='o')
plt.title('F1 Score Across Folds')
plt.xlabel('Fold')
plt.ylabel('F1 Score')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Save the overall performance and fold details
df_fold_details = pd.DataFrame(fold_details)
df_performance = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fold': folds,
    'Train Performance': train_perf,
    'Test Performance': test_perf,
    'Hyperparameters': [str(params) for params in hyperparameters]
})

df_fold_details.to_csv("R_Fasa_XGB_fold_details_with_smote.csv", index=False)
df_performance.to_csv("R_Fasa_XGB_performance_summary_with_smote.csv", index=False)

print("Model training and evaluation complete.")
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Execution time: {toc - tic:.2f} seconds")
```

```
'''
with smote - ROC _ Weights
'''

import time
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, classification_report, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix, roc_curve, auc
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline as ImbPipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_sample_weight




# Function to evaluate model performance
def evaluate_model_performance(y_true, y_pred, y_proba, model):
    """
    Evaluate and display the performance of the trained model.
    """
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
    precision = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
    recall = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
    f1 = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
    print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}, Precision: {precision:.4f}, Recall: {recall:.4f}, F1 Score: {f1:.4f}")

    # Plot confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues')
    plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
    plt.ylabel('Actual label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.show()

    # Plot feature importances if available
    if hasattr(model, 'feature_importances_') and model.feature_importances_.any():
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
        xgb.plot_importance(model, max_num_features=10)
        plt.title("Feature importances")
        plt.show()

    # ROC-AUC calculations and plotting
    # Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
    n_classes = y_proba.shape[1]
    fpr = dict()
    tpr = dict()
    roc_auc = dict()
    # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
    fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_true.ravel(), y_proba.ravel())
    roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
    
    # Plot the ROC curve for the micro-average
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],
             label='micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
                   ''.format(roc_auc["micro"]))
    
    # Plot ROC curve for each class
    for i in range(n_classes):
        fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_true == i, y_proba[:, i])
        roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
        plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
                                       ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=2)
    plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
    plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title('Extension of Receiver operating characteristic to multi-class')
    plt.legend(loc="lower right")
    plt.show()

# Function to display class distribution
def display_class_distribution(y):
    """
    Display the distribution of classes in the label array.
    """
    unique, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
    distribution = pd.DataFrame({'Class': unique, 'Count': counts})
    distribution['Percentage'] = distribution['Count'] / sum(counts) * 100
    print(distribution)

# Start timing
tic = time.perf_counter()

# Data Loading and Preprocessing
print("Loading data...")
Mat = sio.loadmat("/content/drive/MyDrive/Codes/Xgboost_fasa/R_FASA_Binned_spectra_all.mat")
spectraTissue = Mat['spectraTissue']
spectraTissue = savgol_filter(spectraTissue, 5, 4, 0, axis=0)
NHG = [int(x) for x in Mat['label'].T]
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(NHG)
print("Size of spectraTissue:", spectraTissue.shape)



# Initial Class Distribution
print("Initial class distribution:")
display_class_distribution(y)

# Model Training and Evaluation
nsplits = 5
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=nsplits, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

# Store performance metrics for each fold
f1_train_scores = []
f1_test_scores = []
fold_details = []

print("Starting cross-validation with SMOTE...")
for fold, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(skf.split(spectraTissue, y), start=1):
    X_train, X_test = spectraTissue[train_index], spectraTissue[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    # Compute sample weights for the current fold
    sample_weight = compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=y_train)

    # Create an XGBClassifier instance
    xgb_clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softprob', eval_metric='mlogloss', use_label_encoder=False)

    # Create a pipeline with SMOTE and the XGBoost classifier
    pipeline = ImbPipeline([
        ('smote', SMOTE(random_state=42)),
        ('classifier', xgb_clf)
    ])

    # Define the parameter space for GridSearchCV
    paramspace = {
        'classifier__n_estimators': [50, 100, 200],
        'classifier__max_depth': [3, 5, 7],
        'classifier__learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1, 0.2],
        'classifier__subsample': [0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
        'classifier__colsample_bytree': [0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
        # Do not include 'classifier__scale_pos_weight' here since we're passing it in fit method
    }

    # Compute sample weights for the current fold
    sample_weight = compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=y_train)

    # Configure and run GridSearchCV
    grid = GridSearchCV(
        pipeline,
        param_grid=paramspace,
        cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42),
        scoring='f1_macro',
        verbose=2
    )

    # Set up GridSearchCV
    grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=paramspace, scoring='f1_macro', cv=3, verbose=2)

    # Fit the GridSearchCV
    grid.fit(X_train, y_train, classifier__sample_weight=sample_weight)
    print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, sample_weight.shape)

   

    fit_params = {'classifier__sample_weight': sample_weight}
    grid.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    # Get the best estimator
    best_pipeline = grid.best_estimator_

    # Make predictions
    preds_train = best_pipeline.predict(X_train)
    preds_test = best_pipeline.predict(X_test)
    preds_proba_test = best_pipeline.predict_proba(X_test)

    # Evaluate and store metrics for each fold
    f1_train = f1_score(y_train, preds_train, average='macro')
    f1_test = f1_score(y_test, preds_test, average='macro')
    f1_train_scores.append(f1_train)
    f1_test_scores.append(f1_test)
    fold_details.append({
        'Fold': fold,
        'Train F1 Score': f1_train,
        'Test F1 Score': f1_test,
        'Best Params': grid.best_params_
    })

    # Evaluate model performance with detailed report and visualizations
    evaluate_model_performance(y_test, preds_test, preds_proba_test, best_pipeline.named_steps['classifier'])

# Calculate and display average class distribution after SMOTE across folds
print("\nAverage class distribution after SMOTE across folds:")
avg_class_distribution = np.mean([np.bincount(y_train) for _, y_train in skf.split(spectraTissue, y)], axis=0)
distribution_df = create_class_distribution_df(avg_class_distribution.astype(int))
print(distribution_df)

# Results Visualization
# Plot F1 Score Across Folds
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
folds = list(range(1, nsplits + 1))
plt.plot(folds, f1_train_scores, label='Train F1 Score', marker='o')
plt.plot(folds, f1_test_scores, label='Test F1 Score', marker='o')
plt.title('F1 Score Across Folds')
plt.xlabel('Fold')
plt.ylabel('F1 Score')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# End timing and print execution time
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"\nModel training and evaluation complete. Execution time: {toc - tic:.2f} seconds")

# Save the fold details to a CSV file for later analysis
df_fold_details = pd.DataFrame(fold_details)
df_fold_details.to_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Codes/Xgboost_fasa/fold_details.csv", index=False)
```

```
Error: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5ae7e305ec5b> in <cell line: 120>()
    160 
    161     # Fit the GridSearchCV
--> 162     grid.fit(X_train, y_train, classifier__sample_weight=sample_weight)
    163     print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, sample_weight.shape)
    164 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    365                 f"Below are more details about the failures:\n{fit_errors_summary}"
    366             )
--> 367             raise ValueError(all_fits_failed_message)
    368 
    369         else:

ValueError: 
All the 729 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.
```

Class distribution
[image: Class distribution]

Dataset: FTIR output (.mat file) spectral data.
I tried smote, borderline smote, tried svmsmote + easyensemble but still didn't work.
The f1 score is very low and i suspect that is becasue the class 0 is not evenly weighed in the xgboost algorithm.

Any advice or modifications will be highly appreciated.